# getBoundingClientRect() not returning the correct value on window restore down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, d3.js

I have a JS function that runs on the windows-resize event

Within the function, I set a variable `width` to use in resizing my `d3` charts. If I resize the window "manually" (ie: drag one of the window edges), the width variable seems to be correct but when I click the "restore down" icon in the top right of the browser window, the width variable seems not to be correct (if for example, I restore down and the value is 205, one smallest of touches to the window edge and the value is then 310)

```
 root.selectAll('.upload-visual')
                .each(function(d, i) {
                    var me = d3.select(this).select('.chart');
                    var width = me.node().getBoundingClientRect().width;
```

I've read that `getBoundingClientRect()` can be cached for performance reasons.

Is my value being cached or does the function not appreciate what has changed as part of the restore down opertaion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was nothing to do with `getBoundingClientRect()` but certainly something to be aware of.

In the `window-resize` function, the function containing the `getBoundingClientRect()` was being called immediately. I needed to set a timeout to ensure the resize had been finished by the browser so that the correct dimensions were then returned.

Definitely worth knowing